# Triple Stars v/s Ternary Stars

Tags: star-systems

`Ternary` (or `trinary`) stars are not the same as `triple` stars. So, what is the basic underlying difference between these two? What are some popular examples of these two varieties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly the difference between **binary** and **double** stars.

### Trinary System

Three stars gravitationally bound to each other.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_system#Trinary) are some examples

### Triple Star System

Three stars that appear to be together but any one of them is gravitationally unbound.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_star#Triple_star_systems) are some examples.